# Counting distinct elements when memory is limited

Tags: confidence-interval, estimation

How should I estimate the number of unique elements in a randomly shuffled list? I'm in a situation when the memory I have is much smaller than memory needed to store all unique elements. Something efficient with confidence interval and/or a reference for such procedure would be great

Answer (score 3):

Fellow CVer @rrenaud cited [this paper](http://www.vldb.org/conf/1995/P311.PDF) as a key reference for number of unique value estimation. He suggested also to check out the Good Turing frequency estimator, which was developed to estimate the proportion of elements that occur *n* times, including the case where *n* = 1 (i.e., unique values).

[Here is a link to @rrenaud's answer to the similar question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19014/how-can-i-estimate-unique-occurrence-counts-from-a-random-sampling-of-data/19039#19039).

Have fun!

Comment: I agree with the direction suggested. Here is another very good review: http://www.jstor.org/stable/2290733

Comment: It would be good to point to the original question/answer that cited the evidence by rrenaud. I assume you are referring to the answer on this question, [How can I estimate unique occurrence counts from a random sampling of data?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/19090/1036)

Comment: @Andy W that's the one!

Comment: @Andy W: I added a reference to the original answer. Thanks for the stats.exchangeiquette pro-tip. I will observe it in the future!